# Send email in Playwright after tests are executed

Tags: playwright

I need to send email with the playwright report as an attachment. I tried the same using Nodemailer, but its not working. I have tried the code in global teardown, as well as in afterall hooks, but its not sending the mail. However, if I run the same code in a single js file, `enter code here`its working as expected.

I need to send email with the playwright report as an attachment. I tried the same using Nodemailer, but its not working. I have tried the code in global teardown, as well as in afterall hooks, but its not sending the mail. However, if I run the same code in a single js file, its working as expected.

Code snippet:

```
SendEmail(){
try{
  smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'hotmail',
  host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',  
  port: 587,
  rejectUnauthorized: false, 
    auth: {
      user: "SenderEmail",
      pass: "Password",
    },
    tls: {
      ciphers: 'SSLv3',
    },
  });
  console.log("Envelop successfully created");
}
catch(error){
  console.log("Mail envelope not created:"+error);
}
  /*smtpTransport.verify(function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
         console.log(error);
    } else {
         console.log('Server is ready');
    }
  });*/
  const mailBody = {
    from: "senderemail",
    to: "receiveremail",
    subject: "Subject",
    html: "<h1>The Report is attached!</h1>"
  };
  try{
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailBody, function (error, info) {    
      if (error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
      else{
      console.log("Email with attachment delivered successfully");
      }
  });
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.